# SQL- How to update amount(sum) with one time inner join with the multiple row with the same member id

Tags: sql

i plan to update the amount with the 3 row with same member id.

This is what i did

```
DECLARE @UpdatedWagerItem TABLE (MemberID bigint, CompanyID int, amount decimal )
INSERT INTO @UpdatedWagerItem VALUES (3,1,2);

DECLARE @UpdatedWagerItem2 TABLE (MemberID bigint, CompanyID int, amount decimal )
INSERT INTO @UpdatedWagerItem2 VALUES (3,1,5);
INSERT INTO @UpdatedWagerItem2 VALUES (3,1,5);
INSERT INTO @UpdatedWagerItem2 VALUES (3,1,5);

UPDATE m
SET
    m.amount = m.amount + u.amount
FROM @UpdatedWagerItem m 
    INNER JOIN @UpdatedWagerItem2 u 
    ON m.MemberID = u.MemberID and m.CompanyID = u.CompanyID

SELECT * FROM @UpdatedWagerItem
```

[image: sql]

2nd row and 3rd row does not work. How can i update balance with one shot?

Comment: Ryan are you trying to update the 3 columns of @UpdatedWagerItem2 or the one column of @UpdatedWagerItem?

Comment: @zip one column of updatedwageritem amount sum up and update into the first one

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a group by function on your 2nd table to sum up the amount first.

```
UPDATE m
SET
    m.amount = m.amount + u.amount
FROM @UpdatedWagerItem m 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MemberID,CompanyID,SUM(amount) amount
FROM @UpdatedWagerItem2 
GROUP BY MemberID,CompanyID
) u ON m.MemberID = u.MemberID and m.CompanyID = u.CompanyID
```